# Discover/Find the physical location of the "packages" directory a Project is actually using for installed Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, nuget

So I have inherited a project and I just noticed there is a "packages" directory at the solution root and a second "packages" directory inside a project that is part of the solution.

I hope that Nuget is not using a mix of both locations for installed packages and I want to use the solution root level for storing/referencing packages of course.

Is there a way I can find the actual physical location that a project is using for a package other than looking at the F4 properties on each DLL, because this does not help me with Javascript Nuget packages and also, is there a way to change the physical reference without Uninstalling and reinstalling every package?

**Update**
Updating this answer to share what I did so far,even though I have not achieved a solution yet

So I deleted the packages directory in ProjectA and committed to TFS.

I then closed Visual Studio 2012 and made sure that my ProjectA/packages.config remained fully intact, no changes.

I built ProjectA and had reference errors. I then tried running `Update-Package -Reinstall` and this just physically deleted most of my packages and did not reinstall them.

I checked my Nuget.config, I checked my .csproj  I deleted csproj.user and .suo files. I closed Visual Studio 2012 repeatedly. Nothing is giving me a good build again, nothing is restoring my Nuget packages, I have asked a new Question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406566/nuget-is-removing-packages-on-update-package-reinstall-after-moving-packages-di

Comment: If you're using NuGet, you shouldn't be thinking about where the packages are stored on your computer. You add a dependency to a NuGet package and that dependency is resolved using whatever feeds are available. Where the NuGet client puts the actual packages shouldn't be a concern for the developer. E.g. in the new vNext projects the downloaded packages get installed into the framework itself and don't show up anywhere in your solution folder.

Comment: I disagree with that pretty confidently.

If I install a new package and use it in ProjectX and the package is physically stored in ProjectX committed to source control in Projectx, when I want to use the package in ProjectY, the package will be physically installed in AGAIN in ProjectY root, and checked into source control again. Where, if the packages are physically store at the solution root, LIKE THEY ARE SUPPOSED TO BE, VISUAL STUDIO DOES THIS BY DEFAULT, I can install the same package in ProjectY and it is not physically downloaded again. D.R.Y Do Not Repeat yourself, ever.

Comment: When a project is created without a solution and the solution is created later after Nuget Packages have been added to the original project is when you get what I have, packages at the solution level and packages at the Project level, managing packages get very hairy even with Nuget so what you are saying is well, your lack of experience with massive projects, end of story

Comment: Well there's your misunderstanding right there. You're not supposed to commit the packages to source control. You just add the dependencies to NuGet packages, which are committed as part of the csproj files, then restore all dependencies every time you checkout the codebase.

Comment: Also: calm down. There is no need for ALL CAPS SHOUTING.

Comment: Yes you commit the packages directory to source control, have You not ever used a build server?, you do not checkin DLLs from your BIN folder, how would you get the project to build to build successfully without checking in the nuget packages that contain the DLLs you need, you are just wrong, you haven't worked on a larger project with build server, QA server and automated deployment

Comment: The build server restores the nuget packages from feeds, which usually include nuget.org and your private build server itself. You're not supposed to check in the on disk nuget artifacts.

Comment: I agree with @Asad. The whole point of NuGet's Package Restore is so you no longer have to check-in your _packages_ folder. You do have to commit your _packages.config_ file. When the build server checks out the latest code, NuGet will automatically download all the packages listed in the _packages.config_ file. NOTE: This is why I recommend copying all NuGet packages to a local repository. This way the build server is not dependent on nuget.org being up. NOTE2: NuGet.org promises to maintain **all** copies of packages, so you should always be able to build older versions.

Answer (score 7):

As you stated, when you create a project that doesn't have a Solution folder, NuGet will create a *packages* folder in the root of your project. Packages will be installed there and your project will reference assemblies from the project's packages folder.

```
/ProjectA
   /packages
```

When you create a solution and move this project into the solution folder, you end up with something like this:

```
/Solution
   /packages  <= solution packages
   /ProjectA
      /packages  <= packages from original project
   /ProjectB
```

Once you attempt to build this solution, NuGet will see if there are any missing packages in the solution packages folder (such as those from ProjectA). NuGet Package Restore will then download those missing packages into the solution packages folder.

Also, any new packages you add will always be installed in the solution packages folder. Even if you install a package to ProjectA which had its own packages folder.

At this point, you should remove the packages folder in ProjectA. Unfortunately, this causes a problem. The main issue is that ProjectA still has references to assemblies in its own packages folder. When you remove the packages folder, you are not able to build due to missing references.

Luckily, there is an easy fix for this. Simply open up the Package Manager Console and enter:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

This will force NuGet to go through each project and uninstall/reinstall each package. This also ensures that each of the references are now updated to the solution packages folder. NOTE: since the packages were already downloaded, this is a pretty quick process and only needed once to fix-up the references.

Comment: Gotta love nuget, eerily smart it is sometimes lol, thanks Kiliman

Comment: So I have deleted that packages in ProjectA and committed to TFS the delete of this directory, my ProjectA/packages.config remains fully intact, ProjectA.csproj has hint files already pointing to the solution level packages directory ../packages is what you see for the hintpath in ProjectA.csproj, but when I run Update-Package -Reinstall all it does it remove almost all my packages and deletes almost all the packages in /Solution/packages, any suggestions?

Comment: Odd. That's not the experience I had. I actually walked through the process on a sample solution before posting my answer. Anyway, NuGet Package Restore should bring down the packages when you try to build. Does it do that?

Comment: Yes Nuget Package Restore works, as long as I don't run Update-Package - Reinstall after deleting ProjectA/packages and prior to Nuget Package Restore running

Answer (score 0):

So after trying @Kiliman's solution and having hours of issues with broken references etc, I saw the "Enable Package Restore" when right clicking the solution. This was @Asad's solution in the comments.

Nuget developers also recommend that you just Enable Package Restore and do not checkin your packages to source control.

This adds a layer of complexity on some build server setups, you have to ensure that MsBuild restores packages but overall its a smooth transaction and much better than checking in the packages into source control.

Comment: Enable Pack Restore is obsolete. NuGet now has Automatic Package Restore which does not rely on a targets file. I'm sorry my solution isn't working for you. However, it worked as designed on a test project. It sounds like there is an issue with your specific project/setup. My understanding is that you are migrating projects from Solution-less setups. This should be a one-time event.